# PHP SESSION variable not working when decrementing

Tags: php, html

This is my first time using sessions in PHP and it seems I'm doing something logically wrong. I'm coding a forgot password page where the user inputs a randomly generated code to the form and after he clicks submit, displays a message whether the code is correct or not. The user gets 3 attempts to enter the correct code if that's the case is redirected to reset password page else he is redirected to the login page. I'm using a variable called `$_SESSION['attempts']` where it is set to 3 in a previous page and `$_SESSION['code']` variable to store the randomly generated code also from a previous page.

The error message is correctly displayed, that is when the user input the wrong code, the alert dialog pops up and say that he has 2,1 or 0 attempts left and even if the user inputs the correct code, he is redirected to the reset password page. But after it has reached 0 attempt, the redirect does not work. Any idea how to solve this? Thanks in advance.

Here is the PHP code below :

```
 <?php
    
    session_start();
    
    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){

         // input code of the user once it is submitted
        $_code = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'code');
        
       
        if($_SESSION['attempts']  != 0){
            
                // check if code != the generated code
                if($_code != $_SESSION['code']){
                     
                 $_SESSION['attempts']--;
                     
                    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('ERROR : Wrong code entered. You have {$_SESSION['attempts']} attempts left.');</script>";
                     
                //success - redirect to reset password page
                } else {
                    //header to reset password page
                }
        }
                
    }
    
    
    // if attempts === 0 -> redirect to login page (THIS PART DOESNT WORK)
    
    if (($_SESSION['attempts']=== 0 || $_SESSION['attempts'] === '0')) {
        //header to login page
    }
   
?>
```

Comment: Can you share full page code so to test it according and provide you possible solution.

Comment: @MindHunter Can you `var_dump($_SESSION['attemps']);` and share the result in your question, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have put your '**attemp == 0**' condition out of the Post request. Move it to inside of Post request. Then your code should look like below:

```
session_start();

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){

    $_code = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'code');
    
    if($_SESSION['attempts']  != 0){
        
        if($_code != $_SESSION['code']){
                 
        $_SESSION['attempts']--;
                 
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('ERROR : Wrong code entered. You have {$_SESSION['attempts']} attempts left.');</script>";
        
        } else {
            //header to reset password page
        }
    }
    else {
        echo "Now, I need to go login page";
    }
            
}
```

?>

Comment: it still doesn't work even if I put it inside the post request. Once I've reached zero attempts nothing happens..

Comment: You should include the code (I edited my code, you can try again)

Comment: You have to change following line 
if($_SESSION['attempts']  != 0)
into
if($_SESSION['attempts']  >= 0)

And your issue will solve.

Answer (score 0):

Dear Just put one check after session start and for testing this script also put some $_SESSION['code'] value or if you have already than you can proceed with below logic. Remember to put this check on your index or first page where you have defined attempts. Also I have updated your js script and included location.href so that you can see alert before redirection.

```
 <?php

session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['attempts']))
{
$_SESSION['attempts']=3;
}

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){

     // input code of the user once it is submitted
    $_code = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'code');
    
   
    if($_SESSION['attempts']  != 0){
        
            // check if code != the generated code
            if($_code != $_SESSION['code']){
                 
             $_SESSION['attempts']--;
                 
              echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('ERROR : Wrong code entered. You have {$_SESSION['attempts']} attempts left.');location.href='index.php';</script>";
                 
            //success - redirect to reset password page
            } else {
                //header to reset password page
            }
    }
            
}


// if attempts === 0 -> redirect to login page (THIS PART DOESNT WORK)

if (($_SESSION['attempts']=== 0 || $_SESSION['attempts'] === '0')) {
    //header to login page
}
```

?>